# Strange encoding from IMAP connection in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, imap

I am using the PHP IMAP library. I am using my Microsoft 365 email account to test importing the emails from, and some of the message content comes out like this:

```
\x49\x20\x74\x68\x69\x6e\x6b\x20\x41\x64\x72\x69\x61\x6e
```

Not too sure what is going on. When it tries to insert into the Mysql DB via doctrine, it fails (I'm guessing due to the backslashes. Does anyone know what kind of encoding this is, or why I am getting it? Ideally, I would like to decode it, or do I need to change a setting in the IMAP requests?

Thanks.

Comment: It is hex encoding. Looks like it says `I think Adrian`. Backslashes shouldn't cause an issue inserting. What's the error you receive?

Comment: Is it actually encoded that way, or is that an artifact of how you decoded the message, or how PHP shows bytestrings??  (Use view source on your favourite email client to check)  \xNN is not a standard mail encoding so your message is either very weird, or PHP is “helpfully” displaying byte strings that way to you.

Comment: Thanks for the hint it is hex encoding. This is the SQL error i am getting: 
`SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\x96 all ...' for column dbname.email_messages.html_message at row 1`. Please note that the html_message field is definitely a longtext field

Comment: I think i solved it, i think it was just the database disagreeing with the encoding. Have made it convert to UTF-8 encoding before going to the database and that fixed the issue. Thanks for the clues